# How to get all values from checked boxes in HTML form and attribute them to a field

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, checkbox, thymeleaf

I'm trying to use spring + thymeleaf to create a new user.

My models are like that:

```
class Person {
    String name;
    int preferences;
}

class Preferences {
    public static final int no_preferences_checked = 0;
    public static final int receive_newsletter = 1;
    public static final int receive_notification_of_new_jobs = 2;
    public static final int show_email_to_everyone = 4;
    public static final int show_skype_to_everyone = 8;
}
```

In an HTML form users will be presented with 4 check boxes (one for each possible value in Preferences class above.

The preferences field on Person class is the sum of the values of the check boxes explicitly checked by user.

Say, for example, if user checked both receive_newsletter and show_email_to_everyone then preferences field must be 5.

Edit: I think I wasn't clear on my question. Let me rephrase it:

I don't know how to write the HTML form so that *Spring will automatically create the Person class* with all data filled in the method responsible for receiving the post.

It's easy to get the model generated by Spring when there is no checkboxes involved (I followed this [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/) and everything worked fine) but once I've started using check boxes it didn't worked anymore for me. The field preferences never get  filled.

Any suggestion?

Comment: what is the purpose of assigning INTs to your preference fields? Do you use the values for some further processing?

Comment: Just send the checkboxes to the server and do the calculation there... Although I would probably create separate boolean values for the properties. Saves you a lot of hassle with converting from/to the int.

Comment: @Aeseir Instead of have many fields to handle each and every preference, the use of int give me the same information just by applying an OR operation over it. Also, new preferences won't require new fields to be added.

Comment: Best practice is do a bit more coding up front to set yourself up for success. Yes that means more fields to capture and manage, but in saying that if you need to be agile and edit these fields, you can without affecting business processes or other fields in the forms much more rapidly. If you do a combine as you are planning, any slight change to the business logic will result in substantial reinvestment in development & QA.

Answer (score 0):

I think, one way you can achieve this special case, you need to do it in/with javascript.

My suggestions:

Create a javascript file, in this file you have a `checkbox` listener

```
$(':checkbox').change(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    // Your Code
    $('#preferences').val(sum);
});
```

In this method you check which checkbox is checked and read the values of the checked checkbox. Count theses values and assign the counted value to your `preferences` input.
This input can be hidden.